# Modelbuilder only outputs Info files and logs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, modelbuilder

I am developing a processing algorithm in ArcMap ModelBuilder. When I run it everything seems to work fine and running to completion. However when I go check the output directories I only find Info files and Logs, but no output rasters although I have these specified in the model. Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: what is the format of your raster ? maybe you have a grid ? Also you should make sure that the product is not of "intermediate" type, otherwise it is deleted at the end of the run.

Comment: Please add some additional details about the algorithm, such as where the raster is in the process (middle? end result?) to help get a useful Answer.

Comment: A screenshot of the model would be useful, too